# How do I hide the ul's that are not clicked and show submenu in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a dropdown menu using a html list. The jquery code works fine at the first level, but when i try to click something on the list with a submenu it closes and reopens the same list.

How can I get it to open everything but the list i clicked?

```
    // Document Listening
$(document).ready(function () {

    // JQuery running fine, don't need CSS trick for dropdown
    // Remove the class of child and grandchild, this removes the CSS 'falback'
    $("#nav ul.child").removeClass("child");
    $("#nav ul.grandchild").removeClass("grandchild");

    // When a list item that contains an unordered list is hovered on
    $("#nav li").has("ul").click(function (e) {
        $("#nav li").children("ul").not(e.target).slideUp("fast");
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
    });

});

// Document Click 
// Click on anything else other then the link you clicked and close
$(document).mouseup(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest("#nav li").length) {
        $("#nav li").children("ul").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle link with appropriate code ?

Comment: Or, at least post the HTML with your question

Comment: yes,http://jsfiddle.net/mmedi005/qnzsS/

Comment: thank u, sorry for late response, had to step out

Comment: the FLOORS tab should show the floors when you click the city name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because when you click on a submenu, the event is fired for both the clicked li and the parent li. Calling stopPropagation will prevent that.

In addition, when you click on a child li, you slide up all li's other than the clicked li, which also slides up the parent. Change the .not statement to exclude the target and all parents.

```
$("#nav li").has("ul").click(function (e) {
    $("#nav li").children("ul").not($(this).parents()).slideUp("fast");
    $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qnzsS/1/

Comment: just tried in fiddle and cant get floor citys to show 2nd sub menu of floors